What should the <installDir> parameter be for the install4j Maven plugin if install4j does not create a separate directory for Mac OS?
When using the install4j Maven plugin, what should be the value of the  parameter if install4j does not create a separate directory for Mac OS?

On macOS, you specify the path of the application bundle, including the .app extension, so typically
/Applications/install4j.app

